# How to use environment variables in Idea settings

Tags: intellij-idea

Let's say I would like to point to the Maven home via environmental variable, rather than entering the actual path. When I use `"$env.M2_HOME$"` in mavenVersion.xml Idea seems to get it when loading the file:

```
<application>
  <component name="MavenVersion" mavenHome="$env.M2_HOME$" />
</application>
```

I can see the expanded value in `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven` -> Maven home directory.

...but whenever Idea decides to save its settings it does so in their expanded form:

```
<application>
  <component name="MavenVersion" mavenHome="C:/apache-maven-3.3.9" />
</application>
```

I was thinking maybe one could make use of `Appearance & Behavior -> Path Variables` but Idea does not appear to allow entering anything but actual directory/path in `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven` -> Maven home directory.

Am I out of luck here?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support environment variables, you can use Path Variables that work automatically and transparently. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/path-variables.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder As described in the last paragraph, that is what I thought & tried too.

Comment: Did you read how Path Variables work? You never specify the variables in any paths, they are replaced automatically when the project is saved and loaded.

Comment: If it's an option, switch to linux or get a macbook asap. The ability to use symlinks makes everything easier.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Windows has those too, I might actually go that way, good idea sir, thank you :)

Comment: As already stated 2 times, you never enter variables in the input fields, you enter the actual paths. The paths get replaced with variables in the XML configuration files by the IDE when the project is saved. When the project is loaded, the variables get replaced back with the actual paths configured in Path Variables. It works transparently and automatically.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Just realized what you meant. I shall try that, sir! Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Path Variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-path-variables.html) feature will solve this problem.

There is common misunderstanding regarding this feature. Users expect to enter the variables in various IDE dialogs and fields, while it doesn't work this way.

You specify the actual paths as usual and IDE will replace these paths to the corresponding variables in the project XML configuration file. When the project is loaded, IDE will replace the variables back to the actual paths defined in the Path Variables. If this project is opened on a new system where path variable is not defined yet, IDE will ask the user to specify the actual path for this variable.

Another option is to use symlinks on Linux/Mac or junctions on Windows.

Comment: Seems like one has to re-set the Maven directory option so Idea stores it as the path variable reference that has been defined beforehand. It kinda makes sense though. :) I have mavenHome="$MAVEN_HOME$" in mavenVersion.xml now. Thank you!

Comment: The Path Variables link is broken now, is there a simple answer somewhere? Enclose the env variable inside `$VARIABLE$` ?

Answer (score 2):

(an addendum to @CrazyCoder's [response/explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758883/224239))

If you are using **Settings Repository** you want to add `_windows/path.macros.xml` to **.gitignore** in

```
<userhome>/
  .IntelliJIdea<version>/
    config/
      settingsRepository/
        repository/
          .gitignore
```

Otherwise you will be sharing your **Path Variables** across all your machines.